# How to use mysqldump to preserve dbspace name on table statements

Tags: mysql

### Background

We currently dump our database basically like this:

```
mysqldump --complete-insert --opt --hex-blob --all-databases -u -p
```

The dump will look something like this:

```
USE `DB1`

-- Table structure for table `MYTABLE`
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `MYTABLE`
CREATE TABLE `MYTABLE`
...
INSERT INTO `MYTABLE` ...

-- Table structure for table `NEXTABLE`
...

USE `DB2`

-- Table structure for table `MYTABLE`
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `MYTABLE`
CREATE TABLE `MYTABLE`
...
INSERT INTO `MYTABLE` ...

-- Table structure for table `NEXTABLE`
```

### Problem

in some recovery scenarios we need to pull a specific table out of the backup. We might do something like this:

```
cat backup | sed -n -e '/Table structure for table .MYTABLE.$/,/Table structure for table .NEXTABLE.$/p' | mysql -u -p DB2
```

Because the individual table statements do not qualify the dbspace then in this case the table information for `DB1.MYTABLE` is going to be extract and thus `DB2` is going to be populated with the backup from `DB1`

### Question

Is there a way to get the backup to qualify the dbspace name on each table statement such that the `USE` statement becomes unnecessary for this scenario?  E.g.

```
USE `DB2`

-- Table structure for table `DB2`.`MYTABLE`
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `DB2`.`MYTABLE`
CREATE TABLE `DB2`.`MYTABLE`
...
INSERT INTO `DB2`.`MYTABLE` ...

-- Table structure for table `DB2`.`NEXTABLE`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no answer and seemingly no way to add the space name to the dump I am forced to scan the dump differently. Also note that this is a recovery scenario so we cannot simply change the way we already dumped the database as it is too late at that point.

Since the table name within a space is unique what I ended up going with was to first isolate the dbspace instructions in the dump and then isolate that table.

**Use this to restore the table from dump.sql to the same space it came from:**

```
sed  -n '/^USE .SPACENAMEHERE.;$/,/^USE .*$/p' dump.sql | sed -E -n '/^(USE .*;|-- Table structure for table .TABLENAMEHERE.)$/,/^-- Table structure for table /p' | mysql -u -p
```

You will substitute the `SPACENAMEHERE` with the dbspace name and `TABLENAMEHERE` with the table name.  Because this usage of sed will include the `USE` statement in the output we do not need to qualify which database to connect to on the mysql command line.  As long as the user has permissions to "USE" that space it will work.  But if you want to insert this into a different dbspace (i.e. temporary) then you will use this.

**Use this to restore the table from dump.sql to a different space (e.g. a temporary one):**

```
sed  -n '/^USE .SPACENAMEHERE.;$/,/^USE .*$/p' dump.sql | sed -E -n '/^-- Table structure for table .TABLENAMEHERE.$/,/^-- Table structure for table /p' | mysql -u -p DESTINATIONSPACE
```